# How to get last item in array Node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am new to node.js and JavaScript so this question might be quite simple but I cannot figure it out.

I have a lot of items in an array but only want to get the last item. I tried to use lodash but it somehow does not provide me with the last item in the array.

My array looks like this now:

```
images : ['jpg.item_1', 'jpg.item_2', 'jpg.item_3', ..., 'jpg.item_n']
```

and i want to get:

```
images : 'jpg.item_n'
```

Using lodash I am getting:

```
images : ['g.item_1', 'g.item_2', 'g.item_n']
```

It looks like I am just getting the last letter in jpg, i.e. 'g'.

My code using lodash looks like this:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

return getEvents().then(rawEvents => {

  const eventsToBeInserted = rawEvents.map(event => {
    return {

      images: !!event.images ? event.images.map(image => _.last(image.url)) : []

    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `_.last` inside `map`. This will get the last character in the current item. You want to  get the last element of the actual `Array`.

You can do this with `pop()`, however it should be noted that it is destructive (**will remove the last item from the array**).

Non-destructive vanilla solution:

```
var arr = ['thing1', 'thing2'];
console.log(arr[arr.length-1]); // 'thing2'
```

Or, with `lodash`:

```
_.last(event.images);
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But how to I go about it when I want to get the result inside eventsToBeInserted?

Comment: You would do `eventsTobeInserted.push(arr[arr.length-1])`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.pop()` array method

```js
var images  =  ['jpg.item_1', 'jpg.item_2', 'jpg.item_3', 'jpg.item_n'];

var index= images.length - 1; //Last index of array
console.log(images[index]);

//or,

console.log(images.pop())// it will remove the last item from array
```

Comment: This will remove the item though, so he should not.

Comment: @NikxDa correct. did not thoink of that. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Although [`Array.prototype.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) retrieves the last element of the array it also **removes this element from the array**. So one should combine `Array.prototype.pop` with [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var images  =  ['jpg.item_1', 'jpg.item_2', 'jpg.item_3', 'jpg.item_n'];

console.log(images.slice(-1).pop());
```

Comment: Any comments about the downvote? :)

Comment: I did this: `images: !! event.images ? event.images.map(image => image.url.slice(-1).pop()) : []` but now I get an error saying `TypeError: image.url.slice(...).pop is not a function`. Not sure what that means?

Comment: @BjarkeAndersen, most likely it's because the wrong format of `event.images` array. Make sure `image.url` is an array too. I've prepared a little working example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/enzam28p/

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy Simushev